# Como refrescar un select dependiente de otro select

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un select dependiente de otro, en el primero se selecciona el Departamento donde trabaja un usuario y en el segundo select se cargan los usuarios que laboran en ese departamento, esto funciona bien la primera vez que se escoge un departamento, pero si se escoge otro departamento no refresca los nuevos usuarios, sino que mantiene los que cargo con la primera selección.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#project_id").change(function() {
      $("#project_id option:selected").each(function() {
        project_id = $(this).val();
        $.post("ajax/getassigned_user.php", {
          project_id: project_id
        }, function(data) {
          $("#user_id").html(data);
          $("#user_id").multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            selectAllJustVisible: false,
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            buttonWidth: '407px'
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Departamento <span class="required"> * </span></label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select id="project_id" name="project_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">-- Seleccionar Departamento --</option>
      <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
        <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
      </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Asignado a <span class="required"> * </span></label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
    <select id="user_id" name="user_id[]" multiple class="form-control">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Julián, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edita tu pregunta para añadir algo más de información y que pueda ser reabierta: ¿qué hace el código compartido? ¿qué resultado esperas y cuál obtienes? ¿Recibes algún error? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías crear una función llamada rellenarSelect() por ejemplo, en la que por ajax, llamas a getassigned_user.php y le pasas la id a la que quieres traer la lista, y simplemente, llamar a esa funcion cada vez que cambie el primer select.

```
<select id="project_id" name="project_id" class="form-control" onChange="rellenarSelect(this.value)">
```

Añadimos el atributo onChange al primer select pasandole "this.value" para que cuando cambie, coja el valor del option, que sera nuestra id, entonces haces la funcion para traer todos los datos.

```
function rellenarSelect(val){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/miscript.php?id_departament0=' + val,
      onError: function(error){
         console.log('error');
      },
      onSuccess: function(response){
          $('#select2').html(response);
      }
    })
}
```

En el script php deberás controlar los errores y devolver una cadena de texto con todas las options, es decir en el response, deberá haber lo siguiente:

```
 <option value="1">departamento1</option><option value="2">departamento2</option><option value="3">departamento3</option>
```

De tal forma que al llamar a .html() del select a rellenar, automáticamente no borra todas las option de dentro y me mete las nuevas, y al estar en una función que se llama siemrpe que cambia la primera siempre cambiaras el segundo.

Espero que te sirva